# I am new to php ,please tell me ,button click event should add new input tag to existing form through php

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
$('#b1').click(function() {
                $('.frm1').append('<label for="part">Part Name</label><input type="text" name="part" class="lsize"><br><br>');
    });

});
```

Comment: PHP is server side language, i guess you want it client side

Comment: You can't run php code through a user event. you'd need an agax post to comunicate with the server, but you'd need javascript to add a input/dom element

Comment: Why php. Why dont you try with javascript..?

Comment: Click events are handled by client side code so you would need to use JavaScript for that. Do you really want to use a click *event* or are you asking about on form submission? If you do want to use a client event, where does PHP come into it? Are you needing to get some new data from the server before you can generate the input? Are you sure you can't have that data available already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the easest way to solve your problem is to use javascript or a framework like jquery.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('form').append('<input type="text" ... />');
});
```

Comment: hey thank you Patrick this code works fine.now i want to send the values of input tags that i am adding to another form on submit event. can i give different names to input tags that i am adding??

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code, but I would rather use javascript.

Your File (with the ending .php!):

```
<form name="addpart" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"  method="POST" class="frm1">

            <label for="part">Part Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="part" class="lsize"><br><br>

            <button name="b1" type="submit">Add</button>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["b1"])) {

echo('<input type="button">'); // Your HTML input code

}
?>

</form>
```

Comment: That won't work until the form is submitted, then when it shows the form again it will add the button.

Comment: I fixed this. Now it should work.

Comment: still won't add a button until it's gone via the server.

Comment: Works fine for me on my localhost. After clicking the Add button, it adds a new button to the document.

Comment: Yeah, via the server.

Comment: Yes, this code is meant to run on the server. What would you change?